# How to add UICollectionView to the inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, inputaccessoryview

I want to add `UICollectionView` to the `inputAccessoryView` so that I can scroll the list.

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 80))
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return customView
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: i have a list of word . when user enter text in the textfield . I have to suggest this array of list in the collection view cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a `UICollectionView` as `inputAccessoryView`,

**1.** Create a **`custom UIView`** containing a `UICollectionView` first and add the `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods to it.

```
class CustomView: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    let words = ["abscind","downwind","headwind","lind","rescind","sind","skinned","tailwind","thin-skinned","tinned","twinned","upwind","whirlwind","wind"]

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.words.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.label.text = self.words[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}
```

**2.** Add the instance of above created `CustomView` as the `inputAccessoryView` of `UITextField/UITextView` as per your requirement.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? CustomView {
            self.textField.inputAccessoryView = customView
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, you can configure the `collectionView` with data as required.

[image]

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[new.viewControlller:-collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd6d249a870'

Comment: You of course need to connect the `outlets` and create the `xib` files for `CustomView` and `CustomCell`, and create `controller` in the `storyboard` with a `textfield` with connected `outlet`. That very basic thing you should do before proceeding.

Comment: i have already created xib for customView and custom cell and also connect to the viewController . but still got this error

Comment: Have you connected all the outlets? The issue you're getting is the Outlet issue. Cross check all the outlets in `ViewController`, `CustomView` and `CustomCell`.

Comment: no yet this time ---> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key collectionView.'

Comment: Remove the `collectionView` outlet and connect it again. You're connecting the outlet in `CustomView` `xib` and `class` right?

Comment: can you please give me sample that you have tried? i will compare it where i have mistake

Comment: This site can’t be reached

Comment: Updated link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rjq7pm2xezcuivi/InputAccessoryView.zip?dl=0

Comment: thank you soooooo much mam .. I found the problem. and solved it.

Comment: and also how to filter array like user type s in textfield accessory view show "sind","skinned"  according to array of word

Comment: can you please help me ? @PGDev

Comment: Have you given it a try yourself?